# Can you add Defender to an Azure Sql Database with the CLI, ARM or Powershell?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

I found this connect request to add it, but it doesn't say anything about Powershell.   I'm guessing it's not available yet, but can anyone confirm that?

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback/suggestions/42407380-enable-azure-defender-for-sql-using-cli-or-arm-tem

-Randy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Defender only provide the Portal way to enable the defender for Azure SQL database.

There isn't a CLI, ARM or Powershell way to add it. We can continue to vote the [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback/suggestions/42407380-enable-azure-defender-for-sql-using-cli-or-arm-tem) that product team could see it and give us the answer.
[image]

The directly way to get answer is ask [Azure Support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request), but it takes money and time. If you need, you could think about that.

HTH.